# Facing problems while Handling cellForRowAtIndexPath in UITableView when using UISearchController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am creating a `UISearchController` in objective c.I am fetching the contacts from local storage and displaying them in `UITableView`. Able to import and display the values. I am searching the values according to username and i am storing the searched values in an `NSArray` and displaying the searched values according to username. Able to show the username but i am unable to handle the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for showing the details of that particular user like userthumbnail image and user phonenumber.

Below is my code

```
@interface SelectContactViewController (){
     NSMutableArray *contactFullNameArr;
      NSMutableArray *contactPhoneNumberArr;
      NSMutableArray *contactImgPathArr;

    NSArray *searchResultsArray;;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

contactFullNameArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    contactPhoneNumberArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    contactImgPathArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

 [self fetchContactsandAuthorization];

    searchResultsArray = [[NSArray alloc]init];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    _selectContactListTblView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

    [_selectContactListTblView reloadData];


}


-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
    NSString *searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate;
        resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",searchString];
    searchResultsArray = [contactFullNameArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    [_selectContactListTblView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope{
    [self updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self.searchController];
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SelectContactTableViewCell";

    SelectContactTableViewCell *cell = (SelectContactTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SelectContactTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

     if(self.searchController.active){
              cell.contactFullName.text = [searchResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//**************************i am confused here about setting the related user values to the cell************//
             cell.contactProfileImage.image = [contactImgPathArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

         cell.contactPhoneNumber.text = [contactPhoneNumberArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }
     else{
    cell.contactFullName.text = [contactFullNameArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"img %@",[contactImgPathArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    cell.contactProfileImage.image = [contactImgPathArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.contactPhoneNumber.text = [contactPhoneNumberArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 80;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if(self.searchController.active){
        return [searchResultsArray count];
    }else{
    return  contactFullNameArr.count;
    }
}

//for fetching contacts
-(void)fetchContactsandAuthorization
{
    // Request authorization to Contacts
    CNContactStore *store = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
    [store requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted == YES)
        {
            //keys with fetching properties
            NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataKey];
            NSString *containerId = store.defaultContainerIdentifier;
            NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *cnContacts = [store unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:keys error:&error];

            NSLog(@"new %@",cnContacts);

            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"error fetching contacts %@", error);
            }
            else
            {
                NSString *phone;
                NSString *fullName;
                NSString *firstName;
                NSString *lastName;
                UIImage *profileImage;
                NSMutableArray *contactNumbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                for (CNContact *contact in cnContacts) {
                    // copy data to my custom Contacts class.
                    firstName = contact.givenName;
                    lastName = contact.familyName;

                    if (lastName == nil) {
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",firstName];
                    }else if (firstName == nil){
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lastName];
                    }
                    else{
                        fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
                    }
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:contact.imageData];
                    NSLog(@"imgold %@",image);
                    if (image != nil) {
                        profileImage = image;
                    }else{
                        profileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"person-icon.png"];
                    }
                    for (CNLabeledValue *label in contact.phoneNumbers) {
                        phone = [label.value stringValue];
                        if ([phone length] > 0) {
                            [contactNumbersArray addObject:phone];
                        }
                    }


                    [contactFullNameArr addObject:fullName];
                    [contactPhoneNumberArr addObject:phone];
                    [contactImgPathArr addObject:profileImage];
                }
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [_selectContactListTblView reloadData];
                });
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Because of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` not handled properly whenever i search i get the name proper but i get the rest of the details wrong. For Reference

[image]

Now if i search for the second contact that is kate. I am getting John thumbnail and phonenumber mapped to kate. Any help will be really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Make an Object to store all 3 name, phone and image, then store it in only 1 array, then you wont need to deal with array inconsistent

Comment: @Tj3n, thanks for your reply.Can't we handle this without creating an object with 3 names?

Comment: I mean create object that hold name, phone and image for each person, if you dont want to do that, just make 3 `searchResultsArray` to hold similar image and phone when you are searching

Comment: Yes, i want to create 3 seperate searchResutsArray but unable to hold the similar image and phone. Not able to figure out how to do it in 'updateSearchResultsForSearchController'. Any suggestions?@Tj3n

Comment: You cant get index with predicate, you should use another approach like `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest ` to get the index list

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `NSObject` subclasss called `User`
2. Add 3 properties to `User.h` - fullName, phoneNumber, imagePath
3. In `SelectContactViewController` create `User` object for each contact and populate properties with values.
4. Add created `User` objects to array `NSArray *contacts`.
5. Create second array `NSArray *filteredContacts` and use it as UITableView dataSource.

Update `updateSearchResultsForSearchController:` to following:

```
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
    NSString *searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate;
        resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",searchString];
    self.filteredContacts = [self.contacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    [_selectContactListTblView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Left with no option i have created NSObject subclass and created three properties but i kept the imagePath property as UIImage. If you check my above code i am directly storing the UIImage from contact.imageData. App is getting crash at updateSearchResultsForSearchController because i am using UIImage in one of the properties, every property should be string.       *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection <User: 0x7a89e440>@Armands L.

Comment: @Madhu Better convert your UIimage to NSdata / string format

Answer (score 0):

One of my project was similar to this. Please check this for your reference.

```
class StoreVariables: NSObject {
var StoreList : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var StoreMob : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
}
```

firstly I created a class "StoreVariables".

```
var dataArray = StoreVariables()
var filteredArray = StoreVariables()
var shouldShowSearchResults = false
```

then "dataArray" for normal entry and "filteredArray" for keeping filtered list. "shouldShowSearchResults" for checking searchBar use.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     storeclass = StoreVariables() // initialize
      searchbar.delegate = self
  }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if shouldShowSearchResults {
        return filteredArray.StoreList.count
    }
    else {
        return storeclass.StoreList.count
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1") as! storeCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.selectionStyle  = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    if shouldShowSearchResults {
        cell.storeName.text! = filteredArray.StoreList[indexPath.row] as! String
        cell.storeMobile.text! = filteredArray.StoreMob[indexPath.row] as! String
    }
    else
    {
        cell.storeName.text! = storeclass.StoreList[indexPath.row] as! String
        cell.storeMobile.text! = storeclass.StoreMob[indexPath.row] as! String
        cell.delegate = self
    }
  }
```

// SearchBar Delegates

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    shouldShowSearchResults = false
    searchBar.text = ""
    storeTableView.reloadData()
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if !shouldShowSearchResults {
        shouldShowSearchResults = true
        updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchBar)
        storeTableView.reloadData()
    }

}
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    var searchString = searchbar.text
    searchString = searchString!.uppercaseString
    filteredArray.StoreList = []
    filteredArray.StoreMob = []
    if(storeclass.StoreList.count > 0)
    {
    for i in 0...storeclass.StoreList.count - 1{
        var mainString = storeclass.StoreList[i]
        mainString = mainString.uppercaseString
        let chk : Bool = (mainString.rangeOfString(searchString!, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch ).location) != NSNotFound
        if (chk)
        {
            filteredArray.StoreList.addObject(storeclass.StoreList[i])
            filteredArray.StoreMob.addObject(storeclass.StoreMob[i])

        }
       }
    }
}
```